# How to call python scripts from outside project folder to run inside isolated environment

Tags: python, virtual-environment

I'm using python to create various utility scripts for my arch linux machines, and I'd like to do it cleanly inside dedicated environment. Things I can't wrap my head around:

- How can I instruct system (let's say cron) to run rotate-snapshot.py inside my environment? Does system must cd into the project folder first?
- Does all scripts have to be inside a single folder tree (project folder)?
- Do I have to modify shebang somehow in all my scripts?
- I have my own system-wide `run` script that I already use to run all my python/bash/perl scripts. Would it be a good idea to utilize it?
- Scripts are called mostly from non-interactive shells, occasionaly in interactive shell

I suppose there's some smart way to organize this. But how?

Comment: I recently wrote a script with a couple of dependencies tied to its venv. What I found was that by creating a [entry-point specification](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/entry-points/#entry-points) during the build process I can get a script available as an executable in the venv/bin folder which I can execute from anywhere in the system using the absolute path. This avoids the problem of first doing `source venv/bin/activate` and then calling a particular script with Python.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions that seem to work for me:

**#1 - Modify shebangs in all scripts**

Shebang in python script should lead to `<path-to-your-environment>/bin/python`.

**#2 - Run python scripts from another script**

Run script/executable:

```
#!/bin/bash
source <path-to-your-environment>/bin/activate
python "$1" "${@:2}"
```

Or

`<path-to-your-environment>/bin/python "$1" "${@:2}`

Script is also invoked from cron (if executable is placed in `/usr/bin/`).